# Rotate or shift a neon vector by a byte?

Tags: c, assembly, arm64, neon

I want to do the below but avoid the double load

```
isSlash  = vld1q_u8(ptr)   == '\\'
isSlash2 = vld1q_u8(ptr+1) == '\\'
backToBackSlash = isSlash & isSlash2
```

My first instinct was to use a shift but I didn't see a way to shift all 128bits? Next instinct was to use a tbl shuffle but that uses a register which I'll have to do a memory load which means I should just use what I did above instead? Is there another efficient way I may have overlooked? Yes I am processing text and trying to do a backslash escape

Comment: `vext` is the right thing for you.

Comment: Terminology note: `'\\'` is backslash.  `'/'` is slash.  Unrelated to the SIMD problem, but future readers of your code will have an easier time if your var names match what they're looking for.

Comment: @PeterCordes the ironic thing is this code was originally taken from my JSON parser which was actually looking for forward slashes to find comments in nonstandard json files. I should fix the name lol